# displaying values from json in the dropdown list

Tags: jquery, json

http://jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/6/

Please have a look this.

Here while i selecting `DUI Config` values`(DGI,2ddDGI)` i have to display the correpsonding description values in place of `'display DUI description'.`
How it is possible..Code am using is also mentioned in the jfiddle

```
$.each(data.VMs, function (i, vm) {
     if (vm.ID === selected) {
         $.each(vm.ADAPTER, function (j, ad) {
             adapter.push('<option value="' + vm.ADAPTER[j].names + '">' + vm.ADAPTER[j].names + '</option>');
             dui.push('<option value="' + vm.DUIConfig[j].ID + '">' + vm.DUIConfig[j].names + '</option>');
             $('#label').html(vm.DUIConfig[0].description);
             $("#dui").change(function () {

             });
         });
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is because of following

```
"ID": "VM-WIN7-64"
```

And you have initialized

```
selected = 'VM-WIN764';
```

You're checking `if(ID===selected)`  which is always `false`! So your  `if` condition is never satisfied.

Change `selected = VM-WIN7-64` instead `'VM-WIN764'` and everything works!

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/5/)

---

**Update**

You can fire `change()` of your `dui` dropdown and can get the description values. Try with the following code:

```
if (vm.ID === selected) {
        $.each(vm.ADAPTER, function (j, ad) {
            adapter.push('<option value="' + vm.ADAPTER[j].names + '">' + vm.ADAPTER[j].names + '</option>');
            dui.push('<option value="' + vm.DUIConfig[j].ID + '">' + vm.DUIConfig[j].names + '</option>');
            $('#label').html(vm.DUIConfig[0].description);

        });
        //Written Change event here
        $("#dui").change(function () {
            $('#label').html(vm.DUIConfig[this.selectedIndex].description); //Get selected value
        });
    }
```

[**<kbd>Final Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/10/)

Comment: also while selecting first DUIconfig value its description is showing corrrectly..how can i display the description of second one aslo

Comment: not working with your code..Please luk athis 
 
jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/6

Comment: @Sush I found your issue give me a min. i will be back!

Comment: But http://jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/9/ this one is not working ...please look at this also..i tried ur updated code

Comment: @Sush Check out my update once again. Now it's perfectly working :)

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7pJ/10/)